# Unconfirmed Transaction[3]

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, blocktrail

Have problem. Sorry duplicate. and still not understand works[image]

And on Bitcoin-QT

[image]

PS im confused how to back that money ~_~(cancel it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the current fee lever from https://bitcoinfees.21.co/, the fee rate should be 200 satoshi/byte, with you tx, you at least include 0.002 as fees, considering the sending amount. I advise you delete this transaction or wait for the network to forget it. you could have a look this article for more details http://coinour.com/index.php/how-to-do-with-stuck-bitcoin-transaction/